# why tilde and caret charecters does not replace by java replaceAll

Tags: java, string

In java my string reference variable contain the below value

```
String str=".NET CLR Memory~^1~^";
```

now I want to remove ~^1~^ from this. I use replaceAll method as below

```
String str2=str.replaceAll("~^1~^","");
```

but str2 still contain ~^1~^

can any body explain why this and how to remove this.

Comment: Did you read API doc of String#replaceAll()?

Comment: replaceAll() expects a regular expression as first param, and ~ has a special meaning when it is in a regular expression. Unless you escape it using slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), not [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

`replaceAll()` uses *regex* for its target, and your search term is an impossible to match regex.
`replace()` replaces (all occurrences of) plain text.

Do this:

```
String str2 = str.replace("~^1~^","");
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex** and not a String. Solutions:

1. You should escape the [meta-characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). When you do so, the String will be treated as a String and not a Regex.

   Escaping character is done by writing `\` before the Regex, but in Java, `\` is represented as `\\`, so you should write:

   `String str2=str.replaceAll("~\\^1~\\^","");`
2. Another solution is to use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) that takes a String and you'll be fine.
3. Last solution is using [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that takes the Regex and uses it as a String.

   `String str2=str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("~^1~^"),"");`

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you. `~^1~^` not a String.

```
System.out.println(".NET CLR Memory~^1~^".replace("~^1~^",""));
```

Or

```
System.out.println(".NET CLR Memory~^1~^".replaceAll("\\~\\^1\\~\\^",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one.

```
String str=".NET CLR Memory~^1~^";
String str2=str.replaceAll("~\\^1~\\^","");
System.out.println(str2);
```